# Mongoose Update Instance from Nested Array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**In Mongoose**, lets say I have a User object pulled from MongoDB and that user has an array of Interests.  Now I get an instance of one of that user's Interests.

var user = ...
var interest = ...

... //Make some changes to interest.

How do I update that Interest object (after making some changes to it) within the User array in the DB?

**Edit**

Here is my current code.  It doesn't work and doesn't give an error.

```
    User.update(
        {
            '_id': user._id,
            'interests._id': interest._id
        },
        {
            '$set': {
                'interests.$.xyzProperty': interest.xyzProperty
            }
        },
        function(err,obj){//some error checking}
    );
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have some code? If you modify the interest object inside the user object, you should be able to use [`.save`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)

Answer (score 0):

If you set an if for each interest, you can access the interest by the $ operator.

```
user document
{
    _id: ObectId('54b568531ef35a7c348f21f2'),
    interests: [
        {
            _id: 12345,
            title: 'Tacos',
            description: 'I Love tacos'
        },
        {...},
        {...},
    ]
}
```

If I know which interest sub document I want to update, I simply query it like so:

```
UserModel.find({_id: ObectId('54b568531ef35a7c348f21f2'), 'interests.i_d': 12345}).lean().exec(function (err, user) {

    var interest =  ... //find specific interest
    interest.description = 'I love tacos... Like, a lot'.

    UserModel.update(
        {
            _id: user._id, 
            'interests._id': interest._id
        },
        {
            $set: {
                'interests.$.description': interest.description
            }
        },
        function (err, update) {
           console.log(err, update);
        }
    );
});
```

This uses the $ positional operator and updates the specific sub document(or item in an array).

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question because I'm trying to use Mongoose, not mongo commands.

Comment: I'll change it to mongoose commands. They're pretty much exactly the same.

Comment: Also, do some reading here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/ It could be beneficial.